Font with a unique lower case "e"
This is from a label on a pair of jeans from 1984. I have very little to go off of. The only letters I'm 100% about are "S" and "e". Does anyone recognize this, based off the uniquely angled "e"?
Link to pic

It looks like ITC Avant Garde with stylistic alternates on.


That looks dead on. Especially the spacing of the "r". It looks like that might be the missing letter in the second word. Thanks so much!

Thank you for editing my question.
